# Azure HTTP Function -- Encountering issues when creating trigger with OneDrive file input-binding

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app

So I have a requirement to process a file when it is uploaded to a particular folder in OneDrive. An Azure Function would be nice to use for this purpose.

Here's what I see when trying to set this up in the Azure portal:
[image]

Is it even possible to do this in the portal either v3 or v2 of the Azure Functions runtime? I tried to follow the steps [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-microsoft-graph#onedrive-input) but I find them a little less-explicit and difficult to interpret/follow.

If anyone has any better examples to follow, please be so kind to share. I'm confused as to what approach to take (e.g. portal, VS Code, VS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is recommended that we use the classic function UI in azure portal as there are some issues in the new UI.

[image]

And I found that Microsoft Graph bindings are currently in preview for Azure Functions version 2.x and higher. For preview version, we don't recommend that you use them in your production apps.

[image]

The workaround is that you use Azure Logic Apps instead.

Reference:

[Access and manage files in OneDrive connector by using Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-onedrive)

Comment: Thank you. I followed your recommendation and had a good developer experience building my first Logic App. Thanks again!